# Regex if string matches or not

Tags: regex, perl

I've a sample file, created a smaller set of data. I need to get serial and mobile from the file.

```
"3/21/2023, 10:01:01.172 AM",\""serial\"":\""1000001\"",\""mobile\"":\""9999999991\"",\""other keys1\"":\""other values1\""
"3/21/2023, 10:02:01.172 AM",\""mobile\"":\""9999999992\"",\""other keys2\"":\""other values2\""
"3/21/2023, 10:03:01.172 AM",\""serial\"":\""1000003\"",\""other keys3\"":\""other values3\""
"3/21/2023, 10:04:01.172 AM",\""other keys\"":\""other values\""
```

The regex i created-

```
cat temp | perl -pe 's/.*serial\\"":\\""(.+?)\\"",\\""mobile\\"":\\""(.+?)\\"",.*/serials- \1 :::: phone- \2/g'
```

I am getting below result-

```
serials- 1000001 :::: phone- 9999999991
"3/21/2023, 10:02:01.172 AM",\""mobile\"":\""9999999992\"",\""other keys2\"":\""other values2\""
"3/21/2023, 10:03:01.172 AM",\""serial\"":\""1000003\"",\""other keys3\"":\""other values3\""
"3/21/2023, 10:04:01.172 AM",\""other keys\"":\""other values\""
```

What I need is that regex should be eble to print serial and mobile even if one of them is found. If none of them found, nothing should be printed. Right now if both of them are not found, entire line is printed. The actual file that I need to parse is quite big and with many more parameters and if any of the strings (serial or phone) is missing, the entire line clutters the screen.
I need the output like below-

```
serials- 1000001 :::: phone- 9999999991
mobile- 9999999992
serials- 1000003
```

Plz be little elaborative about the regex you provide. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using substitution, you can just use re matching:

```
perl -ne 'print "serials- $1 :::: phone- $2\n" if /.*serial\\"":\\""(.+?)\\"",\\""mobile\\"":\\""(.+?)\\"",.*/
```

EDIT: In response to amended question

More flexible is to match all listed keys, and then format the output appropriately:

```
perl -ne '%match = /\\""(serial|mobile)\\"":\\""(.+?)\\""/g; print(join(" :::: ", map("$_- $match{$_}", keys %match)), "\n") if %match'
```

Output:

```
mobile- 9999999991 :::: serial- 1000001
mobile- 9999999992
serial- 1000003
```

The [`//` matching operator with the `g` flag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#m%2F%2F) returns a list of all the groups (`$1`, `$2`) captured by the pattern.

We assign those to a [hash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata) (`%match`) which uses alternating values in the list as keys/values.

We [`map`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#map-BLOCK-LIST) each key in the `%match` to the formatted version. `map` uses classic terse Perl syntax so we can look a little closer:

```
map("$_- $match{$_}", keys %match)
```

`map` sets the variable `$_` for each of the `keys` in the match (i.e. `mobile` and/or `serial`) and evaluates the expression `"$_- $match{$_}"`. It makes a list of the resulting strings.

We then [join](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#join-EXPR%2CLIST) those strings together using `" :::: "` and print it out.

Comment: it is not printing the lines which have missed either serial or mobile. The logline which has only serial or has mobile string, should be printed partially. And your regex missed ending quote

Comment: Sorry @user2593869 – this was in response to your original question. I'll amend it.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks @motto . I used it on the original huge file I have. Worked like a charm. I've been used to working with SED. I sometimes use PERL for greedy matches. So I don't have much idea about the solution you gave. Can you plz explain a bit about the command, and I would love to practice it, also any reference doc for it !!! Thanks alot for help.